# Latex / PACKAGES/Springer

Tags: packages, installing

I need [`mathptmx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx), [`helvet.sty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/helvet) use Helvet.sty, [`courier.sty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/courier), [`makeidx.sty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/makeidx), [`graphicx.sty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx), [`multicol.sty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol), [`footmisc.sty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) …

Please anyone can provide me those packages?

Comment: Those packages are available via the package managers of TeX Live and MiKTeX. So there shouldn't be a problem with the installation. Can you give us some details about your problem?